# Adding FloatingActionButton in collapsing toolbar layout

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Currently working on a app where I need to add "share" and "add" buttons in the bottom right corner of a `Collapsing toolbar`(*for parallax effect*).

Which might hide on scrolling or might sit on `Actionbar`. Added the image of what i want to achieve. Currently have no clue on how to do this(***tried with floating action buttons with anchors, but failed***).

**This is what is should look like:**

[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/htab_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="13dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/tabIndicatorHeight"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please share that layout or adding it in the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using that in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, you can do this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarCollapse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:minHeight="190dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabmain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/ColorAccent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fabmain2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fabmain2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabmain2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/ColorAccent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

**Also, According to [Google Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html), i don't think if this is the standard way/or good way for two buttons!**

---

Also, this is my idea (standard way):

You could add a `Share action` with that icon on `Actionbar` and then Use one `FloatingActionButton` like this:

https://github.com/xuyisheng/DesignSupportLibraryDemo

---

**Or i did that myself like this:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!--Your content-->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layoutdetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnaildetails"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/imghd"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtitemdetailstitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tbbardetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_work"
        app:backgroundTint="#E91E63"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layoutdetails"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: i know that this is not how it should be done, if you have any better ideas please do share